# Como fazer uma div aumentar ou diminuir usando o touchmove?

Tags: javascript, front-end, javascript-eventos

Estou tentando fazer uma div abrir conforme o usuário arrasta o dedo pra baixo, e fazer ela fechar conforme ele arrasta o dedo pra cima. Pesquisei e vi que eu consigo capturar o toque do usuário na tela com os eventos touch, mas não estou conseguindo fazer ele funcionar.

Esse é o código que desenvolvi até agora:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
 
  var box2 = document.querySelector('#todo'),
    boxleft, 
    startx, 
    dist = 0,
    touchobj = null;
 
  box2.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){
    touchobj = e.changedTouches[0];
    startx = parseInt(touchobj.clientX);
    e.preventDefault();
  }, false);
 
  box2.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){
    document.querySelector("#d1").style.height = "100px";
    e.preventDefault();
  }, false);
 
}, false);
```

```css
#todo {
  background-color: #550000;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

#d1 {
  background-color: #555555;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="todo">
  <div id="d1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Qual problema está tendo? Testei aqui e o código está funcionando normalmente.

Comment: Para testa, abra seu projeto pelo chorme e simule uma janela de `mobile` pelo `Developer Tools`

Comment: Eu gostaria de fazer a div "#d1" aumentar conforme eu arrasto meu dedo para baixo... ela não está fazendo isso =\

Comment: Ela está funcionando agora, que estranho!

Comment: para funcionar, você deve simular uma tela de celular ou usar o próprio celular.

Comment: Eu estava simulando... mas não funcionava